# How to pass an object to axios.post to handle the request in Vue Component?

Tags: object, vue.js, axios, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to pass an object through an axios.post. But apparently, the way I'm doing it is wrong. I'm getting this error

```
Error: "Request failed with status code 500"
```

When I send the data as a normal string I do not have any issues.

My axios.post code looks like this

```
axios.post('/api/send', {
  contactInfo: this.contactInfo
  })
    .then(function (response) {
     console.log(response.data);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      });
```

My contactInfo object is like this...

```
export default {
        name: 'app',
        data() {
            return {

                contactInfo: {
                    email: 'test@test.com',
                    mobile: '11112222'
                }

            }
        },
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. my data are object formed like this, has a value and operand but I need to pass it as string for patch. I'm not sure how to send it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to pass your data is to use this.$data

```
axios.post('url', this.$data)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    })
     .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
      });
```

Comment: what if there are many data objects?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do when I use axios c:

Use FormData and add it data using the .set method like this:

```
// Declare the body
let formData = new FormData ()
// Add data to body
formData.set('name1', variable1)
formData.set('name2', variable2)
// Request
axios.post('url', formData).then(response => {
  // Do something
}).catch(error => {
  // Do something
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The response code is 500 so i think the problem is about your server.

Comment: My server is perfectly fine. As I wrote before, I had to change from this.contactinfo to this.$data and it works now.